# retrieving JSONObject from a file

Tags: android, json, file-io

I wanted to store `JSONObject` in a file.
For the purpose  I converted the Object to string and then stored it in a file.
The code that I used is :

```
String card_string =  card_object.toString();
//card_object is the JSONObject that I want to store.

f = new File("/sdcard/myfolder/card3.Xcard");
//file 'f' is the file to which I want to store it.

FileWriter  fw = new FileWriter(f);
fw.write(card_string);
fw.close();
```

The code works as I want it. Now I **want to retrieve that object** back from the File.
How should I do it? I am getting confused on what to use to read the file ?
an `InputStream` or a `FileReader` or `BufferedReader` or what. I am new to JAVA / android development.

please help. A detailed explanation in simple words regarding what I/O functions to be used in different scenarios (like this) is welcome. I have had a look at documentation but your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569021/read-json-from-assets-folder-into-an-arraylist-in-android

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer. can you also have a look at these questions please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441330/declaring-mime-type-for-a-custom-file-that-is-to-be-sent-via-bluetooth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413498/blue-tooth-file-not-sent-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use could use a `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`:

```
File file = new File("/sdcard/myfolder/card3.Xcard");
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        text.append(line);
        text.append('\n');
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do exception handling
} finally {
    try { br.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

In addition I'd propose that you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` for building up the path. That's less device specific.

Cheers!

Comment: thankyou sir very much ! It is working fine.... can you do me one more favour? please have a look at these questions. really need help over it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441330/declaring-mime-type-for-a-custom-file-that-is-to-be-sent-via-bluetooth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413498/blue-tooth-file-not-sent-error

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to read file.

```
BufferedReader input = null;
try {
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            openFileInput("jsonfile")));
    String line;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int num;
    while ((num = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        content.append(buffer, 0, num);
    }
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content.toString());

}catch (IOException e) {...}
```

Then you can use your jsonObject:

To get a specific string from JSON Object

```
String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

To get a specific int

```
int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
```

To get a specific array

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("listMessages");
```

To get the items from the array

```
JSONObject msg = jArray.getJSONObject(1);
int id_message = msg.getInt("id_message");
```

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer sir. Can you please also have a look at these questions to?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441330/declaring-mime-type-for-a-custom-file-that-is-to-be-sent-via-bluetooth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413498/blue-tooth-file-not-sent-error

Answer (score 2):

```
File contentfile = new File(filePath);
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
FileInputStream readJsonTextfile = new FileInputStream(contentfile);

Reader ContetnUrlJson = new InputStreamReader(readJsonTextfile);
```

Comment: thankyou very much for your answer. can you also have a look at these questions please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16441330/declaring-mime-type-for-a-custom-file-that-is-to-be-sent-via-bluetooth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413498/blue-tooth-file-not-sent-error